# Ubuntu 18.04 Apache automatically crashing frequently for NodeJS Angular based application in AWS EC2 and stopping

Tags: node.js, angular, apache, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on AWS EC2 instance free tier, running websites on Apache server, NodeJS with PostgreSQL database. All deployments are done perfectly and web-apps works fine without any exception or error details.

However I am facing an annoying issue: this instance is stopping frequently without any exception or error logs. After rebooting instance everything starts working fine but after some time it automatically stops either in few hrs. on same day when rebooted instance or in 1-2 days after that.

Below are some Apache logs (var/log/apache2) I tried to analysed but couldn't found out what is causing this exactly:[there is error log is looks related to this:

```
**[Sun Jul 05 14:11:30.444362 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1007:tid 140440680164288] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down]** ]



[Sun Jul 05 13:10:44.389403 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1007:tid 140440680164288] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 05 13:10:44.389524 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1007:tid 140440680164288] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Jul 05 13:10:55.517856 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 1009:tid 140440540890880] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:4200 (localhost) failed
[Sun Jul 05 13:10:55.517921 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1009:tid 140440540890880] [client 27.97.147.181:32952] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
[Sun Jul 05 13:10:55.969159 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 1008:tid 140440582854400] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:4200 (localhost) failed
[Sun Jul 05 13:10:55.969223 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1008:tid 140440582854400] [client 27.97.147.181:25642] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.x6x/
[Sun Jul 05 13:10:59.352669 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 1009:tid 140440549283584] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:4200 (localhost) failed
[Sun Jul 05 13:10:59.352711 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1009:tid 140440549283584] [client 27.97.147.181:12476] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
[Sun Jul 05 13:10:59.687423 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 1008:tid 140440574461696] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:4200 (localhost) failed
[Sun Jul 05 13:10:59.687463 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1008:tid 140440574461696] [client 27.97.147.181:26001] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.x6x/
[Sun Jul 05 13:11:26.091717 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 1009:tid 140440557676288] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:4200 (localhost) failed
[Sun Jul 05 13:11:26.091772 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1009:tid 140440557676288] [client 27.97.147.181:38107] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
[Sun Jul 05 13:11:26.420448 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 1009:tid 140440464520960] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:4200 (localhost) failed
[Sun Jul 05 13:11:26.420481 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1009:tid 140440464520960] [client 27.97.147.181:58238] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost, referer: http://xx.xx.xx.x6x/
[Sun Jul 05 14:11:25.939273 2020] [proxy_http:error] [pid 1009:tid 140440557676288] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 27.97.43.52:50804] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server localhost:4200, referer: http://domain-name.com/sockjs-node/iframe.html
[Sun Jul 05 14:11:25.980501 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 1009:tid 140440557676288] [client 27.97.43.52:50804] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /__webpack_dev_server__/sockjs.bundle.js, referer: http://domain-name.com/sockjs-node/iframe.html
[Sun Jul 05 14:11:30.444362 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1007:tid 140440680164288] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jul 05 14:13:35.011864 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 995:tid 140269259320256] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 05 14:13:35.156051 2020] [core:notice] [pid 995:tid 140269259320256] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had seen this type of issue before and it was DNS issue.
after lots of searches, I found out that the DNS of my domain was not registered correctly.